# Icons of some applications are not loaded properly after upgrading to KDE 6

Tags: kde, tray

I use Nobara Linux 39 KDE as my daily driver. In the recent update of Nobara, KDE 6 has been provided and KDE 5 has been removed completely. After the update, some application icons are not being loaded in the system tray. However, they are identified; those icons are visible in the system tray settings. I am sharing two images.

The following is the screenshot of the system tray settings.
[image]
You can see that the icons are being recognized.
However, in the system tray, some application icons are not loading properly.

[image]

I have tried changing the icon theme and it did not do anything in favor of me.

Is there any way to fix this?